# Debug Mage_Index_Model_Event stock related memory problem during checkout

Tags: checkout, configurable-product, stock, index, memory

This project has around 150k skus with stock management enabled, most of them are configurable products... We've been live with 256Mb php `memory_limit`, but during last weeks we're having *allowed memory* errors during checkout

Errors come when last available unit of a configurable child is sold (stock status change)

We've fixed this raising `memory_limit` to 512Mb, but I'd like to see which data is consuming so much memory, the concrete piece of code firing the error is the `setNewData()` line in `mergePreviousData()` method, in **Mage_Index_Model_Event** class

```
public function mergePreviousData($data)
{
    if (!empty($data['event_id'])) {
        $this->setId($data['event_id']);
        $this->setCreatedAt($data['created_at']);
    }

    if (!empty($data['new_data'])) {
        $previousNewData = unserialize($data['new_data']);
        $currentNewData  = $this->getNewData(false);
        $currentNewData = $this->_mergeNewDataRecursive($previousNewData, $currentNewData);
        $this->setNewData(serialize($currentNewData));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I've checked `$currentNewData` in DB, and it is a very simple and light object, with just some properties... so I suspect problem must be with that `_mergeNewDataRecursive()` previous line, but I am not sure which part of the checkout request is consuming so much memory

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought of using [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, it's hard to guess which line consumes the most memory.

I suggest you use the profile to find out exactly which line is the culprit.

First enable the profiler.

Then update the code with the following:

```
public function mergePreviousData($data)
{
    if (!empty($data['event_id'])) {
        $this->setId($data['event_id']);
        $this->setCreatedAt($data['created_at']);
    }

    if (!empty($data['new_data'])) {
        Varien_Profiler::start('unserialize');
        $previousNewData = unserialize($data['new_data']);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('unserialize');
        Varien_Profiler::start('getNewData');
        $currentNewData  = $this->getNewData(false);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('getNewData');
        Varien_Profiler::start('_mergeNewDataRecursive');
        $currentNewData = $this->_mergeNewDataRecursive($previousNewData, $currentNewData);
        Varien_Profiler::stop('_mergeNewDataRecursive');
        Varien_Profiler::start('setNewData');
        $this->setNewData(serialize($currentNewData));
        Varien_Profiler::stop('setNewData');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Trigger this code (according to your question by selling the last available unit of a configurable child) and check the results.

I know this is not a fix but when you deal with a lot of skus and when you're not on EE, those memory issues are hard to track down.

Comment: This is not what I was expecting (I'd expect to see a trace of all methods fired during checkout for the concrete case, as I guess this is related to the painful way Magento gets simple products of a configurable product) when adding the bounty points, but surely you're right. I'll wait a few & give you the points